# Table problems in PHP

Tags: php, html

This is my current code (and image showing output). I want the table to be aligned and the Names of the values keep repeating. How can I achieve this?

[image: The current OUTPUT]

```
<?php

$country['ph'] = array('Philippines', 'Manila', '+8');
$country['ru'] = array('Russia', 'Moscow', '-4');
$ctr = 1;

foreach ($country as $key => $value) {

                echo '<table border = "1"   >';
                echo '<td>No';
                echo '<td>Flag';
                echo '<td>Code';
                echo '<td>Name';
                echo '<td>Capital';
                echo '<td>Time Zone';   
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>', $ctr++, '</td>';
                echo "<td><img src = \"/csnclass/img/flags/$key.png\"/></td>";
                echo "<td>$key</td>";
                echo '<td>',$value[0], '</td>';
                echo '<td>',$value[1], '</td>';
                echo '<td>',$value[2], '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '</table>';
                }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently, your `foreach` is outputting a `<table>` for each item it iterates through - so the table cells in these tables won't be lined up, as cells in different tables have no relation to each other. Similarly, you're outputting the header of each table column for every single item as well.

A quick way to fix this is to take some of the `echo` calls outside of the `foreach` loop (mainly relating to the table and headers):

```
// Start table and print out headers
echo '<table border = "1"   >';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>No';
echo '<td>Flag';
echo '<td>Code';
echo '<td>Name';
echo '<td>Capital';
echo '<td>Time Zone';  
echo '</tr>';

// Print data for each country
foreach ($country as $key => $value) {          
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>', $ctr++, '</td>';
    echo "<td><img src = \"/csnclass/img/flags/$key.png\"/></td>";
    echo "<td>$key</td>";
    echo '<td>',$value[0], '</td>';
    echo '<td>',$value[1], '</td>';
    echo '<td>',$value[2], '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

// End table
echo '</table>';
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.